# How to transform a string into an ASCII string like in C?

Tags: go

I have to do a cryptography project for my school and I choose Go for this project !

I read the doc but I only C, so it's kinda hard for me right now.

First , I needed to collect the program arguments, I did it. I stockd all arguments in a string variable like :

```
var text, base string = os.Args[1], os. Args[6]
```

Now , i need to store the ASCII number in a array of int , for exemple , in C I would done  something like that :

```
int     arr[18];
char    str[18] = "Hi Stack OverFlow";

arr[i] = str[i] - 96;
```

So how could I do that in Go?

Thanks !

Comment: you're probably better off starting here: http://golang.org/doc/, and specifically: http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions

Comment: I don't understand anything in this page , english isn't my first language and I started programation two months ago , there are too much new things...

Comment: Use Google translate, select English to Russian, drop the url from the website you want to translate. And done! 
a := "Hello World!"
for key, _ := range a {
 fmt.Println(a[key] - 96)
}

Comment: @Dippo: `a := "Hello World!" for key, _ := range a { fmt.Println(a[key] - 96) }` is not a good example.

Comment: @PeterSO That is perhaps true, but the question from the OP is not clear. Also, he is new and i thought, i give him something instead of nothing.

Comment: strings in go are not ASCII and are not indexed by character.  This misunderstanding leads to questions whose answers will also be confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that is similar to the other answer but avoids importing additional packages.

Create a slice of `int` with the length equal to the `string`'s length. Then iterate over the string to extract each character as `int` and assign it to the corresponding index in the int slice. Here's code ([also on the Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/jAG8RBgEkx)):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := "Hi Stack OverFlow"
    fmt.Println(StringToInts(s))
}

// makes a slice of int and stores each char from string
// as int in the slice
func StringToInts(s string) (intSlice []int) {
    intSlice = make([]int, len(s))
    for i, _ := range s {
        intSlice[i] = int(s[i])
    }
    return
}
```

Output of the above program is:

```
[72 105 32 83 116 97 99 107 32 79 118 101 114 70 108 111 119]
```

The `StringToInts` function in the above should do what you want. Though it returns a `slice` (not an array) of `int`, it should satisfy your usecase.

Comment: You fail to address this part of the question: `arr[i] = str[i] - 96;`. You make improper use of the `range` clause: "For a string value, the "range" clause iterates over the Unicode code points in the string starting at byte index 0."

Comment: This solution is reusable and the `str[i] - 96` can be done by the caller. Also, since it uses the primitive constructs of the language, much easier to read. However, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you want something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

// transform transforms ASCII letters to numbers.
// Letters in the English (basic Latin) alphabet, both upper and lower case,
// are represented by a number between one and twenty-six. All other characters,
// including space, are represented by the number zero.
func transform(s string) []int {
    n := make([]int, 0, len(s))
    other := 'a' - 1
    for _, r := range strings.ToLower(s) {
        if 'a' > r || r > 'z' {
            r = other
        }
        n = append(n, int(r-other))
    }
    return n
}

func main() {
    s := "Hi Stack OverFlow"
    fmt.Println(s)
    n := transform(s)
    fmt.Println(n)
}
```

Output:

```
Hi Stack OverFlow
[8 9 0 19 20 1 3 11 0 15 22 5 18 6 12 15 23]
```

Take [A Tour of Go](http://tour.golang.org) and see if you can understand what the program does.